# MVC4 ? (Questionmark) as / (Slash) for action/parameters separator

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I've create a mvc4 application where i need a questionmark as action/parameter separator. This parameter is optional.

`www.mydomain.com?myParam`

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
  "DefaultRoute",
   routeTemplate: "{controller}/{action}?{*param}",
   defaults: new { controller = "Index", action = "Index", param = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

How the route should look like to accomplish this ?

Comment: Query parameters are picked up automatically; you can ignore them in the route.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can build Your URL as usual (with params separated by ? and &). If You define any parameters separated by slash it means that You want Your URL to look more understandable.

If You want Your URL to be in a standard way just remove `param` definition:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
"DefaultRoute",
routeTemplate: "{controller}/{action}",
defaults: new { controller = "Index", action = "Index"}
);
```

Now You can add as many params You want.
For instance Your URL can look like:

```
Index/Index?param1=something&param2=something etc
```

**Updates:**

```
public class IndexController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<MyClass> Index(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
    {
        IEnumerable<MyClass> data = GetSomeData(startDate, endDate);
        return data;
    }
}
```

With the routing specified above You can write:

```
Index/Index?startDate=something&endDate=something
```

And the method will be invoked with these params.

Comment: How to get the parameters ?

Comment: What do You exactly mean?